# How to animate on path with Snap SVG?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg, snap.svg

I am trying to create an animation with snap.svg.

I have created a north and south line, and a circle. I am trying to animate the circle along both paths from bottom to top.

```
var north_line = paper.path("M335.8 137.6v163.1").attr({
  id: "north",
  fill: "#fff",
  strokeWidth: "5",
  stroke: "#000"
});

var south_line = paper.path("M334.3 398v163.2").attr({
  id: "south",
  fill: "#fff",
  strokeWidth: "5",
  stroke: "#000",
  "stroke-dashoffset": bot_line
});
```

Currently I have the animation working but the circle is starting the animation from the top of the line rather than below it, how can I change the direction?

```
var greenCircle = paper.circle(32,32,8);
  greenCircle.attr({
    fill: "#FF5252",
    strokeWidth: 14
  });

  setTimeout( function bottom() {
    Snap.animate(0, bot_line, function( value ) {
       movePoint = south_line.getPointAtLength( value );
       greenCircle.attr({ cy: movePoint.y, cx: movePoint.x }); 
      // move along path via cx & cy attributes
    }, 700,mina.easeinout);
  });
```

This Fiddle should provide more clarity to what I am trying to accomplish.

http://jsfiddle.net/4wLrjmcq/1/

I am trying to figure out to create several circles and have them repeat animating up the path to the top. Would using a loop be best to achieve this to create multiple circles and then have them animate on the path using an interval?

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: As for the directional issue, you can change the coordinates of south_line from `M334.3 398v163.2` to `M334.3 561.2v-163.2` (561.2 being 398+163.2, and the 163.2 in negative to have it go the other way). http://jsfiddle.net/4wLrjmcq/2/

Comment: And here is a question on repeating animations with Snap.svg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206345

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping `0` and `bot_line` in `Snap.animate` that is

```
    setTimeout(function bottom() {
        Snap.animate(
            bot_line,  // <==
            0,         // <==
            function(value) {
                movePoint = south_line.getPointAtLength(value);
                greenCircle.attr({ cy: movePoint.y, cx: movePoint.x });
            },
            700,
            mina.easeinout
        );
    });
```